# Java double to string with specific precision

Tags: java, string, format, double

I would like to convert `double` into `String`. I want it to have as few digits as possible and maximally 6.

So I found `String.format("%.6f", d)` which converts my `100.0` into `100.000000`.
Max precision works correctly, but I would like it to be converted to `100` (minimum precision).
Have you got any idea what method is working like that?

Comment: Have you tried to use the .toString() method?

Comment: or do you mean remove all precision (i.e. cast to int) ?

Comment: Hm, maybe it will be easier with that. At the moment it takes 100.0 > "100.0" but i can cut the end. Also i could cut last digits with substring. If there is no better way then it will use it

Comment: No, want max precision to be 6 numbers, but if there is just 100.0000000 then it should be converted to 100

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `DecimalFormat`: `new DecimalFormat("#.0#####").format(d)`.

This will produce numbers with 1 to 6 decimal digits.

Since `DecimalFormat` will use the symbols of the default locale, you might want to provide which symbols to use:

```
//Format using english symbols, e.g. 100.0 instead of 100,0
new DecimalFormat("#.0#####", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance( Locale.ENGLISH )).format(d)
```

In order to format 100.0 to 100, use the format string `#.######`.

Note that `DecimalFormat` will round by default, e.g. if you pass in `0.9999999` you'll get the output `1`. If you want to get `0.999999` instead, provide a different rounding mode:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.######", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance( Locale.ENGLISH ));
formatter.setRoundingMode( RoundingMode.DOWN );
String s = formatter.format(d);
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a cheap hack that works (and does not introduce any rounding issues):

```
String string = String.format("%.6f", d).replaceAll("(\\.\\d+?)0*$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just make a `setPrecision` function, sort of like this

```
private static String setPrecision(double amt, int precision){
   return String.format("%." + precision + "f", amt);
}
```

then of course to call it

```
setPrecision(variable, 2); //
```

Obviously you can tweek it up for rounding or whatever it is you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

`String.format("%.0", d)` will give you no decimal places

-or-

`String.format("%d", (int)Math.round(f))`