# Converting Double to String. Loses precision

Tags: java, android, string, double

I cannot convert double to string without losing precision.

Look

```
Double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
String latitude1 = Double.toString(latitude);
new onbuttonclickHttpPost().execute(latitude1);
```

Here is async class with rest. And in POST i send String and it is 3.0 which is not acceptable

```
    public class onbuttonclickHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... f_url) {    

        byte[] result = null;
        String str = "";
       // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("_HERE_GO_MY_URL");

        try {

                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng", f_url[0]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "X"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                result = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
                str = new String(result, "UTF-8");
            }
          } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }  

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * on getting result
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // something with data retrieved from server in doInBackground
    }
}
```

String look like this `3.0` but should be `3.518972061574459`

How convert with full precision ?

Edit: add little more code

Comment: double is imprecise but not that imprecise. Its likely that latitude is being truncated before the 1st assignment...post your full code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353319/java-double-to-string-with-specific-precision

Check out decimal format, just a quick search
Happy coding

Comment: How could this happen? Are you sure your double is 3.518972061574459. May be you can post more codes

Comment: Before conversion im sure that latitude is correct (i show that in TextView)

Comment: Did you mean to use Double wrapper class or is it a typo?

Comment: just typo. i update my code. i need pass that double to my server by POST method. please help

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it's right (you can see here that I get all the decimals: http://goo.gl/pORXg2 ). Maybe the problem is how you print it out.

Comment: So.. how i can pass full dobule to POST data in nameValuePairs

Answer (score 0):

try to convert double to String explicitly with format

```
String output=String.format("%.10f", 3.518972061574459);
```

and you'll got "3.5189720615" in output.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you are not using

```
Double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
String latitude1 = latitude==null?"":latitude.toString()
```